# Mismatch in my selection process?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scenario- 
I have to select a series of elements with 2 probabilities:

1. By clicking select all.
2. By selecting individually.

The problem is there is a mismatch if I try to execute both .
My select all and seleting individually is working well. But the problem is when I am selecting all and when I click the individual element then select all doesnot work well.
Below is what I have tried so far . Now please help me to solve this problem so that it works well in all cases i.e
if I am selecting all even after I click any element after selcting it after select all it should work well.
Also Attaching Images to give more clarity:

> Step 1 :

[image]

> Step 2:

[image]

> Step3: The problem area

[image]

```js
$('.SubNavHover li:first-child').click(function() {
  $('.SubNavHover li a').toggleClass('allActive');
  if ($('.SubNavHover li a').hasClass('currentActive')) {
    $('.SubNavHover li a').removeClass('currentActive ').addClass('allActive ');
  }
  if ($(this).nextAll().hasClass('allActive')) {
    $(this).addClass('allActive');
  } else {

    $(this).removeClass('allActive');
  }

});
$('.SubNavHover li a').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('currentActive');
  if ($(this).hasClass('allActive')) {
    $(this).removeClass('currentActive allActive');
  }
  $(this).removeClass('allActive');
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

a.allActive {
  color: blue;
}

a.currentActive {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="SubNavHover" style="opacity:1; visibility:visible;">
  <li><a href="#">Select All </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>


</ul>
```

Comment: So select all should always select all, there is no **unselect** all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with a single class `allActive` like,

```js
$(function() {
  $('.SubNavHover li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ulparent = $(this).closest('.SubNavHover');
    $(this).toggleClass('allActive');
    if ($(this).closest('li.select-all').length) {
      ulparent.find('li:not(".select-all") a').toggleClass('allActive', $(this).hasClass('allActive'));
    } else {
       li = ulparent.find('li:not(".select-all")');
       ulparent.find('li.select-all a').toggleClass('allActive',li.find('a.allActive').length===li.find('a').length);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

a.allActive {
  color: blue;
}
ul{float:left;margin: 0 20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="SubNavHover" style="opacity:1; visibility:visible;">
  <li class="select-all"><a href="#">Select All </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="SubNavHover" style="opacity:1; visibility:visible;">
  <li class="select-all"><a href="#">Select All </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer :)

Comment: thanks.. can we do something like if I am unselecting the selected element after select all (the first element) .. then select all will disable as we are unselecting a element..

Comment: My last problem is if I am using multile menu.. when I select one then all others also get selected... how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

You can check active element by size

This condition solve your problem

```
if($(".currentActive").size() == $(".fa-check").size()){
    $('.SubNavHover li a').toggleClass('currentActive');
}else{
    $('.SubNavHover li a').addClass('currentActive');
}
```

Here is the working code

```js
$('.SubNavHover li:first-child').click(function() {
  if($(".currentActive").size() == $(".fa-check").size()){
     $('.SubNavHover li a').toggleClass('currentActive');
  }else{
       $('.SubNavHover li a').addClass('currentActive');
  }
 
});
$('.SubNavHover li a').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('currentActive');
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

a.allActive {
  color: blue;
}

a.currentActive {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="SubNavHover" style="opacity:1; visibility:visible;">
  <li><a href="#">Select All </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Changed a bit in the JS code.

```js
$('.SubNavHover li:first-child').click(function() {
  $('.SubNavHover li a').addClass('allActive');
  if ($('.SubNavHover li a').hasClass('currentActive')) {
    $('.SubNavHover li a').removeClass('currentActive ')
  }
});
$('.SubNavHover li a').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('currentActive');
  if ($(this).hasClass('allActive')) {
    $(this).removeClass('currentActive allActive');
  }
  $(this).removeClass('allActive');
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

a.allActive {
  color: blue;
}

a.currentActive {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="SubNavHover" style="opacity:1; visibility:visible;">
  <li><a href="#">Select All </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>


</ul>
```

Here is the working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tphbbjck/)

Answer (score 2):

You need remove the class name `selectAll` of all other `li` select and deselect time.

```js
$('.SubNavHover li:first-child').click(function() {
if(!$(this).children('a').hasClass('allActive')){
$('.SubNavHover li a').removeClass('allActive').removeClass('currentActive')
$('.SubNavHover li a').addClass('allActive')
}
else{
$('.SubNavHover li:first-child a').removeClass('currentActive').removeClass('allActive')
$('.SubNavHover li a').removeClass('allActive').removeClass('currentActive')
}

});
$('.SubNavHover li:not(:first-child) a').click(function() {
 $('.SubNavHover li:first-child a').removeClass('currentActive').removeClass('allActive')
  $(this).toggleClass('currentActive');
  if ($(this).hasClass('allActive')) {
    $(this).removeClass('currentActive allActive');
  }
  $(this).removeClass('allActive');
  //console.log($(this).attr('class'))
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

a.allActive {
  color: blue;
}

a.currentActive {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="SubNavHover" style="opacity:1; visibility:visible;">
  <li><a href="#">Select All </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>


</ul>
```